# C# Agregar fila a ListView con TextBox y boton consultando a BD MySQL

Tags: mysql, c#, windows-forms, listview

Hola tengo una duda de como agregar una fila a mi ListView capturando un código de producto en el TextBox y enviando la consulta por Boton o Enter.

"Mi metodo de consulta a MySQL"

```
public DataTable BD_BuscarProductoVenta(string valor)
        {
            MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection();
            try
            {
                cn.ConnectionString = Conectar();
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM producto WHERE codigo like '%" + valor + "%'", cn);
                da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("valor", valor);
                DataTable data = new DataTable();

                da.Fill(data);
                da = null;
                return data;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    cn.Close();
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Error al Consultar: " + ex.Message, "Buscar producto ha fallado", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

"Mi metodo para buscar el producto y agregarlo al ListView"

```
private void Llenar_Listview(DataTable data)
        {
            lsv_venta.Items.Clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = data.Rows[i];
                ListViewItem list = new ListViewItem(dr["idprod"].ToString());
                list.SubItems.Add(dr["codigo"].ToString());
                list.SubItems.Add(dr["descripcion"].ToString());
                list.SubItems.Add(dr["pcosto"].ToString());
                list.SubItems.Add(dr["pventa"].ToString());
                list.SubItems.Add(dr["existencias"].ToString());
                lsv_venta.Items.Add(list); //si no podemos esto., el listview nunca se llenara
            }
            Pintar_Filas();
        }

        public void Buscar_Productos(string valor)
        {
            BuscarElementos obj = new BuscarElementos();
            DataTable dato = new DataTable();

            dato = obj.BD_Buscar_Producto(valor);
            if (dato.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Llenar_Listview(dato);
            }
            else
            {
                lsv_venta.Items.Clear();
                //pnl_no_resultados.Visible = true;
            }
        }
```

"Llamando al metodo desde el boton"

```
private void btnAgregarProdVent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Buscar_Productos(tboxCodigoVent.Text);
        }
```

Luego de trabajar algunos dias con error lo mas que he logrado es que no de error pero no hace nada en absoluto, Ya tengo configurado el ListView pero ese codigo no lo agrego aqui porque es muy comun.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Todo el codigo parece correcto. Si no hace nada, probaste debuguear para ver donde deberia hacer algo y no lo hace? asi como esta, es imposible darte una respuesta porque no la hay

Comment: Ya he debugueado lo mas que pude observa salvo que No marca error simplemente no se agrega la fila al ListView vació. O me llena el ListView con todos los productos o no me trae nada aun cuando no se aprecia error.

Comment: no llena con nada.. eso quiere decir que tu consulta no devuelve nada no.. entonces el problema es tu consulta?

Comment: La consulta si devuelve el codigo de detiene al llegar a la linea Llenar_Listview(dato); Lo siguente: dato = obj.BD_Buscar_Producto(valor); Hasta valor carga el código pero dato ya no recoge información. La unica forma que conozco es pasar todos los Items a Labels ocultos y de ahi retomarlos para añadir la Row al ListView pero no veo que sea buena practica pues he visto que unos programadores sugieren usar el DataRead de MySQL pero no se como implementarlo a mi método de consulta a la BD pues solo fragmentos publican.

Comment: No entiendo. De tu base de datos vuelven datos? Tu lista no se llena con informacion... todo lo que haces lo podes hacer cun reader y serian muchas lineas de codigo menos... ni hablar del gasto de memoria... pero igual, se agrega el item a lsv_ventas?

Comment: Si me trae el código del producto por lo que es suficiente para que me traiga el resto de la fila invocada pero ya ahí queda, creo que si amigo deberé documentarme acerca del uso de Reader pues veo que no esel camino que estoy llevando.